# How to know if my DependencyProperty is set to NULL?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF User Control with several DependencyProperties.

If the user binds "null" to one of my DependencyProperties, I want to be able to do something, for example change the value to something valid.

The problem is that the default value of my property is NULL, and when they set NULL to that property the OnPropertyChanged doesn't fire.

Is there a way to accomplish what I want other than change the default value of my property to something else than NULL? I would need to create some "mock" value to set as default

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can specify a `CoerceValueCallback` when registering your `DependencyProperty`, and use it to substitute a valid value whenever you see a base value of `null`.  Default values are not passed into the `CoerceValueCallback`, so this is pretty much your only option for differentiating between `null` as a default or user value.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty MyPropertyProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        "MyProperty",
        typeof(object),
        typeof(OwnerType),
        new PropertyMetadata(default(object), null, CoerceMyProperty));

private static object CoerceMyProperty(DependencyObject d, object baseValue)
{
    if (baseValue == null)
        return SomeAlternateValue;
    return baseValue;
}
```

If you never assign `MyProperty`, you will see that `CoerceMyProperty` is never called, yet your control instance will have the default value (`null`).  Additionally, given the following two lines, `CoerceMyProperty` will be invoked for the first, but not the second (which reverts to the default value):

```
this.MyProperty = null;
this.ClearValue(MyPropertyProperty);
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are attempting to differentiate between the default value and an explicit user value yet both values are the same: `null`.  This isn't going to be possible because the event is value based and if the value doesn't change the event won't fire.  It sounds like you should look into picking a different default value which is different than `null`.  This will allow you to differentiate between the two states

Comment: You are correct that the `PropertyChangedCallback` will not fire if the *coerced* user value is the same as the default value, but your conclusion is false.  He can differentiate between `null` as a default or user value in that the default value will never be passed to a `CoerceValueCallback`, while the user value will (even if it matches the current, default value).

Comment: For what it's worth, `DependencyPropertyHelper.GetValueSource(obj, dp).BaseValueSource == BaseValueSource.Local` would determine whether it was user-set, but there is still no way to capture the fact that it was set at all if the old and new values are the same. You could perform this check on the control's `Initialized` event though.

Comment: @nmclean I'm not sure what you mean by "there is still no way to capture the fact that it was set at all if the old and new values are the same".  You can observe the set action in the coercion callback, even if you take no other action.  It will always be called when set (but not cleared, or when it has only a default value).  It gets called even if the proposed value matches the current effective value.

Comment: @MikeStrobel That is true, I had a memory lapse. Coerce will work if we want to exclude only the default value, however handling other value sources specially would still present a problem because the ValueSource does not update until after the coerce callback returns.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [DependencyProperty.Register](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597501%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with validate callback

Comment: Unfortunately *Validation callbacks are stored on dependency property identifiers, rather than dependency property metadata. Your validation callback does not have access to a specific instance of a DependencyObject on which the property is set, and can only influence what values are accepted for the property in general. If you need a callback that can change property values based on a specific instance, you should use a combination of a CoerceValueCallback and PropertyChangedCallback.* From the Remarks [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.validatevaluecallback.aspx).