# CoerceValueCallback not called after ClearValue

Tags: wpf, dependency-properties

I have a CheckBox which I have extended to add a IsReadOnly property. The property has a Coerce callback, which will look up access rights for the current user, and return true, if the user does not have permissions:

```
private static object CoerceIsReadOnly(DependencyObject d, object baseValue)
    {
        var owner = (CheckBox)d;

        bool isReadOnly = (bool)baseValue;
        if (isReadOnly == false)
        {
            if (AccessControl.HasFullAccess(owner) == false)
            {
                return true; // If we do not have access, and read only is false, we coerce it to true
            }
        }

        return baseValue;
    }
```

Now I did some experiments to look at the different values:

XAML

```
<vc:CheckBox Content="AccessControl" x:Name="ChkBoxAccessControl" Margin="5" vc:AccessControl.OverrideAccessRights="NoAccess"/>
```

Code-behind

```
var defaultValue = CheckBox.IsReadOnlyProperty.GetMetadata(typeof(CheckBox)).DefaultValue; // False
var localValue = ChkBoxAccessControl.ReadLocalValue(CheckBox.IsReadOnlyProperty); // Unset (we didn't set a value in code or XAML)
var actualValue = ChkBoxAccessControl.GetValue(CheckBox.IsReadOnlyProperty); // True (coerced)

ChkBoxAccessControl.SetValue(CheckBox.IsReadOnlyProperty, false);
var localValue2 = ChkBoxAccessControl.ReadLocalValue(CheckBox.IsReadOnlyProperty); // False
var actualValue2 = ChkBoxAccessControl.GetValue(CheckBox.IsReadOnlyProperty); // True

ChkBoxAccessControl.ClearValue(CheckBox.IsReadOnlyProperty);
var localValue3 = ChkBoxAccessControl.ReadLocalValue(CheckBox.IsReadOnlyProperty); // Unser
var actualValue3 = ChkBoxAccessControl.GetValue(CheckBox.IsReadOnlyProperty); // false??? WTH...
```

So to my surprise, the last actualValue3 returns false.

Apparently when calling ClearValue, it does not call the coerce callback. Is this to be expected? Can anyone explain why this would be correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this to be expected?

Yes, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21115867/7252182) answer. When you clear the value, you get the default non-coerced one.

Also, `actualValue` isn't coerced in your example but `actualValue2` is.

A dependency property stores and remembers the non-coerced value. You can read more about this [here](https://wpf.2000things.com/2010/12/10/151-dependency-properties-remember-non-coerced-values/).

Comment: Ok I see. The reason actualValue is in fact true then, is because we coerce it manually in OnApplyTemplate... Thanks.